# Rails- add hash to redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to specify a hash to add to a redirect_to.  How do I do this?

This is how my redirect_to is formed:

```
 redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @consultant.id
```

I need to go to example.com/consultant/#some_hash

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try `redirect_to your_current_options, :anchor => 'fragment_identifier'`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem. I tried this:

```
redirect_to @post, anchor: 'tab_items'
```

but not worked using rails 4.2.6. But if I've changed to the following, and now works fine:

```
redirect_to post_path(@post, anchor: 'tab_items')
```

Comment: That's correct. The anchor attribute belongs to the path and url helpers, not redirect_to